# ajax通信でsql文を送信し、結果を取得する方法

Tags: php, monaca, ajax

お世話になっております。
現在、Monaca側からAjaxとphpを利用して、外部DBのレコードを取得しています。

表題の件ですが、検索のクエリをAjaxでPOST送信して、PHPでPDOを使った
クエリ実行を行うまでは出来ました。

しかし、DBから取得したデータを返す際、JSON形式に変換する必要があり、
今の所手動で連想配列を作り、それをjsonへ変換しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ですがこのやり方だと、クエリによって連想配列作成のロジックを
変更しなければならない為、sql文だけを送って結果を取得するという
ことが実現できません。

どうにかして実現できる方法はないでしょうか？
言っている事が分かりにくかったらすみません。

ご回答頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の回答については
PDOの結果を配列で返してくれるようなライブラリが存在するのでそちらを使ってはどうでしょうか？
http://php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: ご回答頂き有難うございます。

fetchall をつかってみたら、全件取得できました！
しかしテーブルのフィールドが3つある場合、
1レコードにつき何故か6つのデータが戻ってきます。
(A,A,B,B,C,C というように重複しています）

Comment: まずは質問する前に回答に記載しているリンク先のPHPマニュアルを読み込んでください。

fetch_styleのパラメータを指定することで、返ってくるレコードが指定できます。
「PDOStatement::fetch() に文章化されているような 返される配列の内容を制御します。」とあるのでリンク先の
http://php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.fetch.php
こちらを参考にすると
「そのデフォルトは PDO::FETCH_BOTH」とあり「PDO::FETCH_BOTH (デフォルト): 結果セットに返された際のカラム名と 0 で始まるカラム番号で添字を付けた配列を返します。」となっています。他を調べると「PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: は、結果セットに 返された際のカラム名で添字を付けた配列を返します。」とあるのでこちらの定数を利用すれば期待の返り値になると思います。

Comment: 申し訳ありません、よく読まずに質問してしまいました。それなのに親切にご回答頂き、本当に有難うございます。教えて頂いた内容を元にやってみます。ご回答頂き有難うございました。